# How to get content of element tag html

Tags: typescript

It is possible to get only the context of "n" element tag inside a string using typescript.

```
string = "<h1>Just survive</h1><p>Of such great powers or beings there may be conceivably a survival... a survival of a hugely remote period when . . . consciousness was manifested, perhaps, in shapes and forms long since withdrawn before the tide of advancing humanity . . . forms of which poetry and legend alone have caught a flying memory and called them gods, monsters, mythical beings of all sorts and kinds...</p>"
```

wanted output:

> Just survive Of such great powers or beings there may be conceivably a survival... a survival of a hugely remote period when . . . consciousness was manifested, perhaps, in shapes and forms long since withdrawn before the tide of advancing humanity . . . forms of which poetry and legend alone have caught a flying memory and called them gods, monsters, mythical beings of all sorts and kinds...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn the HTML string into an element with DOMParser, then take its `textContent`:

```
const string = "<h1>Just survive</h1><p>Of such great powers or beings there may be conceivably a survival... a survival of a hugely remote period when . . . consciousness was manifested, perhaps, in shapes and forms long since withdrawn before the tide of advancing humanity . . . forms of which poetry and legend alone have caught a flying memory and called them gods, monsters, mythical beings of all sorts and kinds...</p>"
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(string, 'text/html');
console.log(doc.body.textContent);
```

Comment: And if the iframe, img tag will get parse too?

Comment: An iframe is a completely separate window - if you want to access its text content, you'll have to have control of its URL as well, and you'll have to go into it manually through `iframe.contentDocument.body.textContent` when encountered. Images do not have any content, they're void elements.